# Find overlapping between intervals in Javascript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, intervals

I have the following intervals with start time and end time:

```
{ status: 'A', start: 12:20, end: 12:35},
{ status: 'B', start: 12:21, end: 12:28},
{ status: 'C', start: 12:22, end: 12:30},
{ status: 'D', start: 12:30, end: 12:45},
{ status: 'E', start: 12:40, end: 12:48}
```

As you can see, there are some overlaps, like: `12:22 -->12:28` that includes `A, B, and C` statuses. or `D and E` that have `12:40 -->12:45` overlap. All the data are sorted based on their start time. How can I write a program in Javascript to have the overlaps and their correspondent statuses?

Basically, the output would be the following:

```
[A, B, C] : {12:22 , 12:28}
[D, E] : {12:40 , 12:45}
...
```

Current code finds two overlaps:

```js
const schedule = [
      { status: 'A', start: '12:20', end: '12:35'},
      { status: 'B', start: '12:21', end: '12:28'},
      { status: 'C', start: '12:22', end: '12:30'},
      { status: 'D', start: '12:30', end: '12:45'},
      { status: 'E', start: '12:40', end: '12:48'}
    ]
    const intervali = {start: '', end:'', status:''};
    for (i = 0; i < schedule.length - 1; i++) {
      interval_i = schedule[i];
      for (j = i + 1; j < schedule.length; j++) {
         interval_j = schedule[j];
        if (interval_j.start < interval_i.end && interval_j.end > interval_i.start) {
          intervali['start'] = interval_i.start > interval_j.start ? interval_i.start : interval_j.start;
          intervali['end'] = interval_i.end < interval_j.end ? interval_i.end : interval_j.end;
          intervali['status'] = interval_i.status + ' - ' + interval_j.status;
          console.log(intervali)
        } 
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using nested loops?

Comment: You have them, they're right there.

Comment: @VtoCorleone Yep, but it doesn't return all the overlapping intervals.

Comment: @Mvarta What? Where? read the question and description carefully

Comment: @Enayat Read your question carefully: .. "How can I write a program in Javascript to have the overlaps and their correspondent statuses?"

Are you trying to find the length of time that is overlapping? Are you trying to find which objects overlap? Are you trying to combine them? Where's some actual code? What have you tried?

Comment: @Mvarta I have written a sample of output: the name of status, and the actual overlaps. The output should be sth like: A, B, and C, the overlap area: 12:22 -->12:28

Comment: @Enayat Mvarta was being sarcastic. Looks like you just want someone to write code for you. On S.O. is is appropriate to show your effort, and where you're stuck.

Comment: So, you output should be something like [[A, B, C], [D, E]] is it?

Comment: @NanduKalidindi Yes.  [[A, B, C]:{12:22 -->12:28}
[D, E]: {12:40 -->12:45}

Comment: @AndréWerlang He or she did not comment properly. He said, 'they are right there'. I could find overlaps between two objects but I could not find the three overlaps. I will modify the question accordingly. Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested loops to loop over each item twice and run a comparison. Please see comments below.

```js
const schedule = [
  { status: 'A', start: '12:20', end: '12:35'},
  { status: 'B', start: '12:21', end: '12:28'},
  { status: 'C', start: '12:22', end: '12:30'},
  { status: 'D', start: '12:30', end: '12:45'},
  { status: 'E', start: '12:40', end: '12:48'}
]

// convert a time string to integer of minutes
const toMinutes = time => {
  const [hour, minute] = time.split(':')
  return (Number(hour) * 60) + Number(minute)
}

function findOverlappying(schedule) {
  
  const l = schedule.length
  const ret = {}
  
  // loop over each item twice
  for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < l; j++) {

      const left = schedule[j]
      const right = schedule[i]
      
      // set the status to the return object
      ret[left.status] = ret[left.status] || {
        ...left,
        overlap: []
      }
      
      // don't process for the same key
      if (i === j) {
        continue
      }
      
      // get the start and stop times as minutes to compare
      const leftStart = toMinutes(left.start)
      const leftStop = toMinutes(left.end)
      const rightStart = toMinutes(right.start)
      const rightStop = toMinutes(right.end)
      
      // compare the start and stop times for overlapping
      if (
        (leftStart > rightStart && leftStart < rightStop) ||
        (leftStop > rightStart && leftStop < rightStop)
      ) {
        // add time to overlapping status identifier
        ret[left.status].overlap.push(right.status)
      }
    }
  }
  return ret
}

console.log(
  findOverlappying(schedule)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```